# How can i save data on a database from a html pasted in a texarea or similar?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

first of all I want to clarify that I have read the suggestions but I did not find an exact answer.

I want to make a database locally by saving in this parts of a html page code, and I'm going to use it locally only, i use Wampsever 3.

I want to make a page in a local in which I can paste HTML code and parts of this code are saved in a database, the code is dynamically generated so I think it has no error, and always i will paste a DIV element with a TABLE with ROWS.

The code is something like this:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>

        <tr class="month">
            <td colspan="5">Jan</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="day-info">
            <p>xxx</p>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dataofday">
            <div class="info1">
                <p>yyy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="info2">
                <p>zzz</p>
            </div>
        </tr>

        <tr class="day-info">
            <p>xxx</p>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dataofday">
            <div class="info1">
                <p>yyy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="info2">
                <p>zzz</p>
            </div>
        </tr>

        <tr class="month">
            <td colspan="5">Feb</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="day-info">
            <p>xxx</p>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dataofday">
            <div class="info1">
                <p>yyy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="info2">
                <p>zzz</p>
            </div>
        </tr>

        <tr class="day-info">
            <p>xxx</p>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dataofday">
            <div class="info1">
                <p>yyy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="info2">
                <p>zzz</p>
            </div>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And i need to save in a database the rows with classes "day-info" and class="dataofday", both in the same row of a table in a a database but in different cells.

I can create the database, i can get the elements with Jquery or Javascript but i do know how can i save the data in a database from a page in local where i can paste the DIV with the data.

So i need some help for create it and save the data to a DB.

Am i rigth if my first step is to create a .html or .php file into a virtual host in Wampserver with a code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<textarea rows="40" cols="100">
...Here paste the data.
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

and maybe with new DOMDocument i can get the data, parse it and save it to th database.

Comment: Use AJAX to process your data and save it in the database

Comment: i need to paste files up to 70 MB, i'm not sure if i can do this with AJAX.

Comment: Well you can do a more PHP approach by placing your textarea in a form and process everything in PHP once the form is submitted

Comment: You say that i only save the data in a database only using PHP without using AJAX?